# Audio conversion and filter application using ffmpeg with 1 command

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an mp3 file I need to convert to wav, and apply loudnorm filter afterwards. So far i've been doing it with 2 commands.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 output.wav
```

and

```
ffmpeg -y -nostdin -i output.wav -filter_complex "[0:0]FILTER PARAMETER" -map_metadata 0 -map_metadata:s:a:0 0:s:a:0 -map_chapters 0 -map [norm0] -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 1500 -c:s copy out2.wav
```

Is there anyway to use 1 command instead of 2?  I tried converting straight from mp3 to out2.wav by changing output.wav to input.mp3, but when the resulting file is compared with diff, they are different compared to the 2 step process.

I'm fairly new to ffmpeg, and have spent hours on the documentation without really knowing how to accomplish what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Just use one-step process. With your two steps, ffmpeg first converts from floating point to 16 bit signed integer in first command and then in 2nd command, loudnorm may upsample that to 192 kHz before ffmpeg resamples to 1500 Hz. Due to rounding differences, the result won't match the one-step process.

Comment: so, are you saying, i can just replace the input in step 2 with the original mp3 file (i.e. input from step 1)?

Comment: That's right...